# PyQt5 закрытие окна не прерывающее скрипт

Tags: python, pyqt5

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно вывести PyQt окно подождать пока юзер нажмёт на кнопку, закрыть окно и продолжить скрипт. Кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Именно так и делать - вывести окно, закрыть окно и продолжить скрипт не убивая его через `sys.exit(...)` или же отловил вызванное этой функцией исключение `SystemExit`.

Comment: Можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 1):

Перепробовал все варианты, и понял, что лучше всего подходит метод **close()**

Comment: Ну, в общем-то да, вызвать `close()` при нажатии на кнопку и продолжить без принудительного завершения скрипта `sys.exit(...)`. Все правильно, мне добавить нечего. Думаю, пример уже не нужен?

Answer (score 0):

А что если как-то так:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore    import QPropertyAnimation, Qt, QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QFontDatabase
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QPushButton, QApplication, QStyleOptionButton,
                             QStylePainter, QStyle)

class PushButtonFont(QPushButton):

    LoadingText = "\uf110"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PushButtonFont, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(250, 250)
        self.fontSize = self.font().pointSize() * 2
        self._rotateAnimationStarted = False
        self._rotateAnimation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        self._rotateAnimation.setTargetObject(self)
        self._rotateAnimation.setStartValue(1)
        self._rotateAnimation.setEndValue(12)
        self._rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000)
        self._rotateAnimation.setLoopCount(-1)                 # Бесконечная петля
        self._rotateAnimation.valueChanged.connect(self.update)
        self.clicked.connect(self._onClick)

    def paintEvent(self, _):
        option = QStyleOptionButton()
        self.initStyleOption(option)
        painter = QStylePainter(self)
        if self._rotateAnimationStarted:
            option.text = ""
        painter.drawControl(QStyle.CE_PushButton, option)
        if not self._rotateAnimationStarted:
            return
        painter.save()
        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(self.fontSize)
        font.setFamily("FontAwesome")
        painter.setFont(font)
        #  преобразовать координаты в середину
        painter.translate(self.rect().center())
        # поворот на 90 градусов
        painter.rotate(self._rotateAnimation.currentValue() * 30)
        fm = self.fontMetrics()
        # Положительный средний текст после преобразования координат
        w = fm.width(self.LoadingText)
        h = fm.height()
        painter.drawText(
            QRectF(0 - w * 2, 0 - h, w * 2 * 2, h * 2), Qt.AlignCenter,
            self.LoadingText)
        painter.restore()

    def _onClick(self):
        if self._rotateAnimationStarted:
            self._rotateAnimationStarted = False
            self._rotateAnimation.stop()
            return
        self._rotateAnimationStarted = True
        self._rotateAnimation.start()

    def update(self, _=None):
        super(PushButtonFont, self).update()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Загрузка шрифтов в библиотеку шрифтов
    QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(
        "Fonts/FontAwesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf")
    w = PushButtonFont("Нажмите, чтобы загрузить "
                       "fa_spinner")  
    w._onClick()                 
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]